# The Index of an element in a direct product

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm having a bit of trouble.

I know that the index of $a$ in $\mathbb{Z}_m$ is equal to $\frac{m}{|a|}$ Where $|a|$ is the order of $a$ in $m$.

But say we have a direct product of $\mathbb{Z}_m \times \mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}_r$. Would this imply the index is equal to $\frac{(m)(n)(r)}{|a|}$ or would it be $\frac{lcm(m,n,r)}{|a|}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of any element $(a, b, c) \in \mathbb{Z}_m \times \mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}_r$ is $lcm(|a|, |b|, |c|)$.

Hence, the index of the cyclic subgroup generated by that element is:

$$\frac{| \mathbb{Z}_m \times \mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}_r|}{lcm(|a|, |b|, |c|)} = \frac{m \cdot n \cdot r}{lcm(|a|, |b|, |c|)}$$